Robot broken links in Gazebo
This is an error that only happens sometimes, randomly, without any other indication of error.
The robot appears with some of its links "exploded", like in the picture:

I am using gazebo 11.10 and a bunch of custom plugins (to disable physics, move platform...)
These are the log lines related to gazebo. There are some errors there, that might be related, but those appear always and error happens only sometimes
[gzserver-3] Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2
[gzserver-3] Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
[gzserver-3] Released under the Apache 2 License.
[gzserver-3] http://gazebosim.org
[gzserver-3] 
[gzserver-3] [INFO] [1727868211.504297384] [third_person_camera]: Publishing camera info to [/third_person_camera/camera_info]
[gzserver-3] [Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_control.so: libgazebo_ros_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[gzserver-3] [INFO] [1727868211.676304815] [set_joints_position_plugin]: Loaded SetJointPositions gazebo plugin. Watching topic: /joint_states
[gzserver-3] [Wrn] [ModelDatabase.cc:340] Getting models from[http://localhost:8099/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
[gzserver-3] Warning [parser.cc:833] XML Attribute[type] in element[model] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
[gzserver-3] Topic [default/ee_9636_jA/ee_cam_left_link//ee_9636_jA/ee_camera_left/image] is not valid.
[gzserver-3] Topic [default/ee_9636_jA/ee_cam_right_link//ee_9636_jA/ee_camera_right/image] is not valid.
[gzserver-3] [INFO] [1727868213.715903464] [rclcpp]: Received request to attach model: 'robot' to 'ee_9636_jA
[gzserver-3] Warning [parser.cc:833] XML Attribute[type] in element[model] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
[gzserver-3] Topic [default/ee_9636_jC/ee_cam_left_link//ee_9636_jC/ee_camera_left/image] is not valid.
[gzserver-3] Topic [default/ee_9636_jC/ee_cam_right_link//ee_9636_jC/ee_camera_right/image] is not valid.
[gzserver-3] [INFO] [1727868214.626291071] [rclcpp]: Received request to attach model: 'robot' to 'ee_9636_jC
[gzserver-3] [Msg] Waiting for master.
[gzserver-3] [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[gzserver-3] [Msg] Publicized address: 172.17.33.6
[gzserver-3] [Msg] Loading world file [/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/bmt_common_bringup/share/bmt_common_bringup/config/gazebo/empty.world]
[gzclient-48] [Msg] Waiting for master.
[gzclient-48] [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[gzclient-48] [Msg] Publicized address: 172.17.33.6
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/bmt_9636_bringup/share/ament_index"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/bmt_9636_bringup/share/bmt_9636_bringup"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/bmt_9636_bringup/share/colcon-core"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/bmt_fastening_bringup/share/ament_index"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/bmt_fastening_bringup/share/bmt_fastening_bringup"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/bmt_fastening_bringup/share/colcon-core"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/ur_description/share/ament_index"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/ur_description/share/colcon-core"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/ur_description/share/ur_description"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/rbrobout_boeing_description/share/ament_index"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/rbrobout_boeing_description/share/colcon-core"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/rbrobout_boeing_description/share/rbrobout_boeing_description"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/rbrobout_description/share/ament_index"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/rbrobout_description/share/colcon-core"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/rbrobout_description/share/rbrobout_description"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/robotnik_sensors/share/ament_index"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/robotnik_sensors/share/colcon-core"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/deps/install/robotnik_sensors/share/robotnik_sensors"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/ewellix_driver/share/ament_index"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/ewellix_driver/share/colcon-core"
[gzclient-48] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/lruiz/ros/bmt/install/ewellix_driver/share/ewellix_driver"

This is the appearance of the robot when correctly loaded:

Any idea of what could be causing this error?

I had the same situation going on with my robot (in the same Gazebo version) for a caster wheel.  In my case, if I moved the bot in X, the caster ball moved with the bot, but when I rotated about Z the ball did not stay with the bot and became wild.
Apparently setting the joint to "ball" was not sufficient info, I would have needed three links (one for each axis) with inertia and three joints that would get combined by Gazebo into one link.
Since I don't have anything hanging off the ball joint, I can get away with just setting the joint type to "fixed" and no more lost caster ball.

Perhaps this link will help you:
https://answers.ros.org/question/258420/ball-joint-in-urdf/
